# Forcing a particular altitude in a contour plot to have a specific color

Tags: plotting

How can a particular altitude in a contour plot be forced to have a particular color, despite the applied color function? (Specific to my case, the altitude of 0).

Comment: do you happen to have a MWE? that will make it easier to answer.

Comment: The easiest way would be to add a constant, but this might depend on what you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach that post-processes the contours:

```
ClearAll[formatContour]
formatContour[value_, format__: Red] := 
 HoldPattern[Tooltip[{Directive[color_, directives__], graphics__}, value]] :> 
  Tooltip[{Directive[format, directives], graphics}, value]
```

I constructed this after inspection of the output of `InputForm` of a `ContourPlot`. We can then apply it as follows:

```
cp = ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}];

cp /. formatContour[0]
```

[image: default modification]

... or you can specify directives:

```
cp /. formatContour[0.2, Blue, Thickness[0.02]]
```

[image: blue 0.2]

Answer (score 2):

#### 1.  [`Exclusions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html) + [`ExclusionsStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExclusionsStyle.html)

```
Row[ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
    ImageSize -> Medium, 
    Exclusions -> {Sin[x y] == #}, 
    ExclusionsStyle -> {Red, Red}] & /@ {0, .4}]
```

[image]

#### 2. [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) + [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) + [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html)

```
Row[ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
    ImageSize -> Medium, PlotPoints -> 100,
    MeshFunctions -> {Sin[# #2] &}, 
    Mesh -> {{#}}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Purple, Thick]] & /@ {0., .4}]
```

[image]

#### 3. [`ContourStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourStyle.html)

```
minmax = #[{Sin[x y], -Pi/2 <= x <= Pi/2 && -Pi/2 <= y <= Pi/2}, {x, y}] & /@ 
  {NMinValue, NMaxValue}
```

> ```
> {-1., 1.}
> ```

```
Row[ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
  ImageSize -> Medium, 
  ContourStyle -> (Replace[N@Rest@FindDivisions[minmax, 10], 
     {# -> Directive[Magenta, AbsoluteThickness[3], Dashed], _ -> Automatic}, {1}])]&/@
   {0., .4}]
```

[image]

#### 4. [`Contours`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Contours.html)

```
Row[ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
    ImageSize -> Medium, 
    Contours -> ((N@FindDivisions[minmax, 10] /. 
       # -> {#, Directive[Thick, Green]}))] & /@ {0., .4}]
```

[image]